# Why parts of my script run more than once?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to find a line from a given CSV file, and parse it.

Here's my script. It's in `Extract.bat`:

```
@echo off

findstr "%DomainName%" C:\LocalSecrets\Deployment.csv > /Temp/Found
set Command=findstr "%DomainName%" C:\LocalSecrets\Deployment.csv

for /F "usebackq" %%A in ('/Temp/Found') do set Size=%%~zA

if (%Size%) == (0) echo Nothing found for [%DomainName%]
if (%Size%) == (0) exit /b

for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%a in ('%Command%') do call :parcsv %%a

:parcsv
echo "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%~4" "%~5"
set Domains=%~1
set FtpUsername=%~2
set FtpPassword=%~3
set DatabaseHost=%~4
set Database=%~5
```

And here's the `C:\LocalSecrets\Deployment.csv` content:

```
domains,ftpUsername,ftpPassword,databaseHost,database
"example.com,admin.example.com",example.com,kasouzxclkjoiuwelrkjlsd,localhost,Example
"new.example2.ir,admin.example2.ir",example2.ir,xldkwuclxksker,localhost,Example2
"new.example3.com,admin.example3.com",example3.com,knidklcislekrjsl,localhost,Example3
```

If you call `Extract.bat example3.com` You get this response:

```
"example3.com,admin.example3.com" "example3.com" "knidkslcislekrjsl" "localhost" "Example3"
"" "" "" "" ""
```

As you can see, the last line of the result should not be there. Why my code is run twice?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to *exit the script* at the end, so it simply continued into the section after `:parcsv`.

`:parcsv` is only a GOTO label – it doesn't define a "function", doesn't create a new scope; the interpreter will go through the *whole* script from top to bottom.

(Although later Windows versions made it possible to call such labels as subroutines through `call :label`, this didn't fundamentally change the script's structure – it still works as a single block of code, and even the called subroutines do not automatically return until they hit the end.)

To avoid this, you need an `exit /b` or `goto :EOF` after your "main" code (and also at the end of every "subroutine" if you have more than one).

```
@echo off
findstr ...
for /F "usebackq" ...
if (%Size%) == (0) echo Nothing found for [%DomainName%]
if (%Size%) == (0) exit /b
for /F ... do call :parcsv %%a
goto :EOF

:parcsv
echo "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%~4" "%~5"
set Domains=%~1
set FtpUsername=%~2
set FtpPassword=%~3
set DatabaseHost=%~4
set Database=%~5
goto :EOF

:additionalsubroutine
do something...
goto :EOF

:someothersubroutine
do something...
goto :EOF
```

If you want real functions (and a [real CSV parser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-5.1)), use PowerShell instead.